# What can be harmed by incorrect power off, and what can be checked?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, shutdown

What, if anything, should I be worried about after several improper shutdowns and power issues? (Ubuntu Server 17.04)

The short version of my story is the shutdown process would trigger my motherboard's circuit protection against unstable power supplies, at which point the computer would immediately power off and power back on to the post screen with a warning message. The same thing would happen if I tried to put the hard drives in standby with hdparm -y.

Replacing the power supply solved this problem, though I'm embarrassed to admit how long it took me to figure that out.

Is there anything I should check, or corrective actions I can take? Reinstalling the operating system (again) wouldn't be the worst thing in the world, but I'm wondering if I should bother. System disk is an SSD, and two WD Red drives in mirrored Btrfs for media storage.

Comment: Welcome aboard, congratulations to this excellent first question! +1

Comment: Hopefully someone write a detailed answer with fsck-like commands, but in short: if you have EXT4 anywhere, it is very stable against such situations. But BTRFS is bad in this because of deduplication. Upon power loss it can leave screwed files which you never touched, because of the deduplication. I have had two such situations on an external drive, and ended up migrating to ext4.

Comment: Hmm... system is EXT4. Interesting note about btrfs, but I don't think I've ever used deduplication. That's not something that happens automatically, is it?

Comment: You can also use the `halt` command, and then manually poweroff the computer after it shows the black screen for a few minutes, just like in the old days when computers said "Its now safe to turn off your computer"

Comment: Deduplication is automatic, it's a feature of BTRFS. I don't know whether it can be disabled though.

Comment: @Ferrybig, it isn't the type of shutdown that was the problem, but the fact that something as simple as putting my hard drives in standby (cutting the power draw of this computer by more than half) was somehow causing psu issues. The psu has since been replaced.

Comment: Oh yes, improper shutdown can be hard to debug. For months, my phone was freezing on shutdown, the phone (thinking it's smart), "resolved" the freeze by rebooting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to check the `ext4` file system is to add

```
fsck.mode=force
```

as a boot parameter.

It can be done in `/etc/default/grub`, or manually on boot.

For older systems that use `upstart` run

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

and reboot.

The command will create an empty `/forcefsck` file that will tell the system to check drives on boot.

On boot, before the file system is mounted `fsck` will run and show if there are errors.

Otherwise you will need to boot from some external device.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything, normal boot. I read somewhere that this doesn't work on systemd based systems? Or is it just really that fast...

Comment: It used to work with upstart. I don't use `ext4` for a long time and didn't notice that it doesn't work. But there must be some way to do the same with systemd.

Comment: @User4574 I added how to do it with `systemd`.

Comment: Had to look up adding boot parameters in grub, but this appeared to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu's standard `ext4` file system in an Ubuntu standard partition can be checked with the following command

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn
```

or if you also want to check for bad blocks (physically bad blocks)

```
sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, for example `/dev/sda1`.

See `man e2fsck` for details.

You should boot from another drive, a live drive, for example a rescue linux drive or an Ubuntu desktop live drive, and *the target partition should **not** be mounted* when you run this command.